# Slim 3 render method not valid

Tags: php, slim

I want to make simple template rendering in Slim3 but I get an error:

Here is my code :
namespace controller;

```
class Hello
{
    function __construct() {
// Instantiate the app
        $settings = require __DIR__ . '/../../src/settings.php';
        $this->app = new \Slim\App($settings);
    }

    public function index(){
        return $this->app->render('web/pages/hello.phtml');   //LINE20
    }
}
```

This is the error I get :

```
Message: Method render is not a valid method
```

Answer (score 2):

The `App` object doesn't handle any rendering on its own, you'll need a template add-on for that, probably [this one](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html#the-slimphp-view-component) based on your template's `.phtml` extension. Install with composer:

```
composer require slim/php-view
```

Then your controller method will do something like this:

```
$view = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('./web/pages');

return $view->render($response, '/hello.phtml');
```

You'll eventually want to put the renderer in the dependency injection container instead of creating a new instance in your controller method, but this should get you started.

Comment: I get this : `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: controller\Hello::$view` and `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function render() on a non-object`

Comment: @smile22121 I made the example code a bit more explicit, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: Thank you but seems to be something wrong in $response : I got this `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Slim\Views\PhpRenderer::render() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, integer given`

Answer (score 0):

I handle this by sticking my renderer in the container. Stick this in your main `index.php` file.

```
$container = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$app = new \Slim\App($container);
$container['renderer'] = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer("./web/pages");
```

Then in your `Hello` class's file.

```
class Hello
{
   protected $container;

   public function __construct(\Slim\Container $container) {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function __invoke($request, $response, $args) {
        return $this->container->renderer->render($response, '/hello.php', $args);
   }
}
```

To clean up this code, make a base handler that has this render logic encapsulated for you.